# Get response from Kafka producer after each send command

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using spring boot Kafka to send messages to a topic.
My requirement is to read data incrementally from a table and publish it into a topic based on a date time field and as it is a scheduled process i need to store the date-time field from each message after each
successful send message to Kafka.

Any suggestions what is the best way of doing this.I believe i cannot use asynchronous callback for something like this as i need to update the variable after each call to the producer.

Also i cannot use Kafka connect due to infrastructural constraint.

Answer (score 0):

```java
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = template.send(...);
SendResult<String, String> sendResult = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Long timestamp = sendResult.getProducerRecord().timestamp();
```

If the send fails, the get will thrown an exception.

Comment: Does this method waits before sending another message?

Comment: Yes, calling `get()` on the future waits for it to complete; to speed things up, you can do multiple sends and save the futures in a `Collection` and wait for them all later.